# Checking collisions in near objects for random object spawning in Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I have almost finished my first game in Unity, which is a simple maze with characters collecting different coins. As it was a hassle to manually put all the different coins in the terrain, I decided to try and make a random generator for the coins.

The script is largely working, but the problem is that it's spawning objects most of the time inside walls. So I tried to add rigid bodies to coins, but this is messing with the coins position as the coins have a script for rotation. I also have the coins collision triggered because they perform a certain action when colliding with the character.

So after some research I saw that I need to check in my generator script for a near object collision and somehow change the spawn position of the coin if it's true. I'm trying to figure out how I can do that. My script is attached to my terrain and it looks like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using CustomArrayExtensions;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{

[SerializeField] public GameObject[] letters;

    GameObject selectedObject;

    private int amount = 0;

    public int limit;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnObjects());
    }


    IEnumerator SpawnObjects()
    {

        selectedObject = letters.GetRandom();

        while (amount < limit)
        {
            Instantiate(selectedObject, new Vector3(Random.Range(35.0f, 950.0f), 13.0f, Random.Range(35.0f, 950.0f)), Quaternion.identity);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.0f);
            amount++;
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Fox_Main")
        {
            Debug.Log("Collision Detected");
        }
    }
}
```

So i tried both answers and they didn't help me.Coins and other objects is still spawning close/inside the walls.My boxes have box collider and rigidbody with all positions/rotations locked(i need it that way so that i can destroy it later without moving it with the character),walls have box collider.So i tried to modify your solutions following Unity Documentation.I failed too.Here is what i have done so far.
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBXBj.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class RandomCrates : MonoBehaviour
{
  public GameObject[] crates;
  private GameObject selectedCrate;
  public int limit = 0;
  public float x, y, z;
  public float forX_From,forX_To,forZ_From,forZ_To;     
  private int mask = 1 << 7;

  void Start()
  {
      StartCoroutine(SpawnObjects());
  }

  IEnumerator SpawnObjects()
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < crates.Length; i++)
      {
          for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++)
          {
              Vector3 freePos = GetFreePosition();
              Instantiate(crates[i], freePos, Quaternion.identity);
              yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.0f);
          }
      }

  }

  Vector3 GetFreePosition()
  {
      Vector3 position;
      Collider[] collisions = new Collider[1];
      do
      {
          position = new Vector3(Random.Range(forX_From, forX_To), 10.0f, Random.Range(forZ_From, forZ_To));
      } while (Physics.OverlapBoxNonAlloc(position, new Vector3(x, y, z), collisions, Quaternion.identity, mask) > 0);

      return position;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity provides a simple way to detect collisions in specific position with [Physics.OverlapSphere](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html):

```
public class ObjectSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] public GameObject[] letters;
    GameObject selectedObject;
    private int amount = 0;
    public int limit;
    private float radius = 2f; //Radius of object to spawn

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnObjects());
    }


    IEnumerator SpawnObjects()
    {

        selectedObject = letters[Random.Range(0, letters.Length)];

        while (amount < limit)
        {
            Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(35.0f, 950.0f), 13.0f, Random.Range(35.0f, 950.0f));
            //Check collisions
            if (DetectCollisions(spawnPos) > 0)
                continue;

            Instantiate(selectedObject, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.0f);
            amount++;
        }
    }

    private int DetectCollisions(Vector3 pos) 
    {        
        Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(pos, radius);
        return hitColliders.Length;
    }

}
```

In this way, if there is a collision in spawn position, the coin will not be spawned.

Comment: thank you a lot for reply.I'll give it a try.The game is very simple so i assume there should't be any problems.

Comment: can you explain me what the 0 is for in the if condition?Because i dont want the coint not to be spawned at all but instead i want it to be spawned in another location after the collision detection.

Comment: If DetectCollisions (spawnPos) is greater than zero, it means a collision has occurred. In this case, the contiune keyword takes us to the beginning of the while loop before spawning the coin and creates a new random position. We only increase the "amount" value when the spawn a coin properly. In this way, you can spawn as many coins as you want.

Comment: If i have a maze its best to check for 3 collisions to occur before spawning the coin.Correct?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by 3, but I think the code is suitable for your example.

Comment: I mean,imagine having a maze generator, wich makes 1) cells and deletes 1 wall and repeats the steps until the maze is complete,then we have 3 walls wich we should check for collisions.Am i right?

Comment: If the coin will spawn before the wall and then the wall will spawn in the same position is it possible for collisions not to be detected?

Comment: If you run the coin generator after than the maze generator completed, there'll be no problems. You can do this control with events. Otherwise, walls can be spawned on coins.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of approaching this problem and given more information one could come up with a smarter approach. However, to provide you with a simple solution to your problem: You could just pick random positions until you find a "free spot".
Assuming your coins to have a size of 1, you could do something like:

```
IEnumerator SpawnObjects()
{
    selectedObject = letters.GetRandom();

    while(amount < limit)
    {
        Vector3 freePos = GetFreePosition();
        Instantiate(selectedObject, freePos), Quaternion.identity);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5.0f);
        amount++;
    }
}

Vector3 GetFreePosition()
{
    Vector3 position;
    Collider[] collisions = new Collider[1];
    do
    {
        position = new Vector3(Random.Range(35.0f, 950.0f), 13.0f, Random.Range(35.0f, 950.0f));
    }
    while(Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc(position, 1f, collisions) > 0);

    return position;
}
```

**Please note** that `Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc()` can also accept a [LayerMask](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html) for filtering collisions based on layers. You might want to look into this, to prevent detecting collision with your terrain, which may well keep the do-while loop from exiting and freeze Unity.

Comment: i see you give quite a good approach to my problem.But because my coins is floating higher and not on terrain maybe it's not needed to do that.What is your suggestion?Ty a lot for replying to me.